# How do I create a comment with Ajax in Rails 5?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, erb

I am not sure if i am passing post correctly but the comment is still getting created and when I look at my index.html.erb page on the browser it works fine.

I keep getting this error in my terminal once i post a comment.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `post' 
for #<#<Class:0x007fc9c544ee90>:0x007fc9c527f498>
Did you mean?  @post):
1: <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
2: <tr id="comments_<%= comment.id %>">
3:  <td><p><%= comment.user.email %></p></td>
4:  <td><p><%= comment.content %></p></td>

app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_comments__comment_html_erb__2743602892026494484_70252313407540'
app/views/posts/show.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_posts_show_html_erb__792041857476014578_70252313539340'
```

Here is my Comments Controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_post
before_action :find_comment, only: [:destroy,:edit,:update,:comment_owner]
before_action :comment_owner, only: [:destroy,:edit, :update]

def create

    @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.save

    respond_to do |format|
        if @comment.save
            format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Comment was successfully created' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
            format.js
        else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            format.js
        end
    end
end

def edit

end

def update
    if @comment.update(params[:comment].permit(:content))
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
end

private

def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id]) 
end

def find_comment
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
end
def comment_owner
    unless current_user.id == @comment.user_id
        flash[:notice] = "Nice trick ;P"
        redirect_to @post
    end
end

def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
end
end
```

My index.html.erb

```
<tbody>
<%= render @posts%>
</tbody>
```

My _post.html.erb

```
<tr id="<%= post.id %>">
    <td><%= post.id %></td>
    <td><%= post.title %></td>
    <td><%= post.content %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="edit_button" data-
     target="#myupdatepost_<%= post.id %>">Edit</button></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, remote: true %>
</td> 
</tr>
```

from here i am trying to pass the post to the next partial

```
    <%= render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: {post: post} %>

  <tr class="EP <%= post.id %>">
<%= form_for(post, :method => :put, remote: true) do |form| %>

<td class="field">
    <%= form.label :title %>
    <%= form.text_field :title, id: :post_title %>
</td>

<td class="field">
    <%= form.label :content %>
    <%= form.text_area :content, id: :post_content %>
</td>

<td class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
</td>

<% end %>
</tr>
```

Here is _comment.html.erb

```
<% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
<tr id="comments_<%= comment.id %>">
<td><p><%= comment.user.email %></p></td>
<td><p><%= comment.content %></p></td>  

<% if current_user == comment.user %>
<td><%= link_to "Delete Comment", [comment.post, comment], method: 
:delete %></td> 
<td><%= link_to "Edit Comment", 
edit_post_comment_path(comment.post,comment) %></td>
<% end %>
</tr> 
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => 'comments/form', :locals => {:post => post} %>
```

And finally here is _form.html.erb

```
<tr class="Comm <%= post.id %>">
    <%= form_for([post,post.comments.build], remote: true) do |f| %>
        <td><%= f.text_area :content %></td> 
        <td><%= f.submit %></td>
<% end %>
</tr>
```

Here is my create.js.erb for the comment

```
console.log("ajax working coment created");
$("textarea#comment_content").val("");
console.log("<%= @post.title %>");
console.log("<%= @comment.content %>");
$("tbody").append("<%= j render(@comment) %>")
```

Comment: can u show posts controller ?

Answer (score 1):

> undefined local variable or method `post'
>
> Did you mean?  @post

Try using @post

Edit: Your code should be in _comment.html.erb

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
<tr id="comments_<%= comment.id %>">
<td><p><%= comment.user.email %></p></td>
<td><p><%= comment.content %></p></td>
<% if current_user == comment.user %>
<td><%= link_to "Delete Comment", [comment.post, comment], method: :delete %></td>
<td><%= link_to "Edit Comment", edit_post_comment_path(comment.post,comment) %></td>
<% end %>
</tr>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => 'comments/form', :locals => {:post => @post} %>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<tr class="Comm <%= @post.id %>">
<%= form_for([@post,@post.comments.build], remote: true) do |f| %>
    <td><%= f.text_area :content %></td> 
    <td><%= f.submit %></td>
<% end %>
</tr>
```

Comment: I did, but then i another error to put the @ over every post there after.

Comment: Now i have this error ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments", :post_id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:post_id]): in _form.html.erb

Comment: `@post` is an instance variable, it represents a @post setted in post controller probably. So your code should looks like (edit in answer)